# Ionic component - all red in VSCode html editor

Tags: html, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, ionic5

I am using VSCode to write my Ionic5 app. While autocompletion of HTML code works and the editor recognizes all specific Ionic html keywords, it fails to do so when I edit a HTML of an ionic component that only has the inner body of a page, not the whole page.

For instance, my component starts with

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center" >
    <ion-col size="9" (click)="openFullView()">
```

and all `ion` keywords are marked in red as "unknown element" . If I use them in a proper Ionic page, all's well. I guess I am missing a VSCode setting or an include in my source?

EDIT:
I ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67008367/ionic5-prod-build-error-unknown-component?noredirect=1#comment118456649_67008367) issue and I think it is related. Add `IonicModule` to the component. It is missing in the ionic boilerplate code.

Comment: Be sure that no other extension that takes part on the visualization of the HTML is causing problems.

Comment: Yep, nothing is. Any idea?